# create dynamic table using multidimensional array and store data in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, use-state

I am noob in reactjs,I have started learning it this month, here I am trying to create useState variable which has data stored in  way of multidimension array, or just array. input for this variable comes from dynamic tables cells, which get created based on row number and column number.
this link has table part created, i am facing issue with storing data in array

https://codesandbox.io/s/new-glitter-lepkk?file=/src/demo.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
// Material-ui imports
import { fade, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650
  }
});
const BootstrapInput = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "label + &": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
    }
  },
  input: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    position: "relative",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    border: "1px solid #ced4da",
    fontSize: 16,
    width: "60%",
    padding: "5px 6px",
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["border-color", "box-shadow"]),
    "&:focus": {
      boxShadow: `${fade(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.25)} 0 0 0 0.2rem`,
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main
    }
  }
}))(InputBase);

export default function DataTabelVariable() {
  // Table
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [rowValue, setRowValue] = useState(0);
  const [columnsValue, setColumnsValue] = useState(0);
  const [tableCellsData, setTableCellsData] = useState();

  // const [jsonVar, setJsonVar] = useState({});
  // var dictVarKey = {};
  // var dictVarValue = {};
  // var jsonVar = {}


  const getUniqueKeyFromArrayIndex = (rowNum, columnNum) => {
    return `${rowNum}-${columnNum}`;
  };
  // const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  //   console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value);
  //   setTableCellsData({
  //     ...tableCellsData,
  //     [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  //   });
  // };

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    setTableCellsData({
      ...tableCellsData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
    // console.log(Object.keys(tableCellsData));

    // for (var key in tableCellsData) {
    //   var value = tableCellsData[key];
    //   const splitVar = key.split("-");
    //   if (parseInt(splitVar[0], 10) === 0) {
    //     dictVarKey[splitVar[1]] = value;
    //   } else if (parseInt(splitVar[0], 10) > 0) {
    //     dictVarValue[splitVar[1]] = value;
    //   }
    // }

    // for (var Kkey in dictVarKey) {
    //   for (var Vkey in dictVarValue) {
    //     if (Kkey === Vkey) {
    //       jsonVar[dictVarKey[Kkey]] = dictVarValue[Vkey];
          
    //     }
    //   }
    // }
    // console.log(dictVarKey);
    // console.log(dictVarValue);
    // console.log(jsonVar);
    //   for (let i = 0; i<rowValue; i++){
    //     for (let j=0;j <columnsValue; j ++ ){

    //     }

    //   }
  };

  const generateTable = () => {
    let table = [];
    // Outer loop to create parent
    for (let i = 0; i < rowValue; i++) {
      let children = [];
      //Inner loop to create children
      for (let j = 0; j < columnsValue; j++) {
        children.push(
          <td>
            <BootstrapInput
              name={getUniqueKeyFromArrayIndex(i, j)}
              onChange={onChangeHandler}
            />
          </td>
        );
      }
      table.push(
        <TableRow key={i}>
          <TableCell>{children}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      );
      // console.log(tableCellsData);
    }
    return table;
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <h5>Select Row number and Columns number</h5>
        <div className={"rowColumnsNumber"} style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <TextField
            id="Row-number"
            label="Row(s)"
            type="number"
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
            inputProps={{ min: "0", max: "1000", step: "1" }}
            onChange={(e) => setRowValue(e.target.value)}
            variant="outlined"
          />
          <TextField
            id="Columns-number"
            label="Columns(s)"
            type="number"
            inputProps={{ min: "0", max: "1000", step: "1" }}
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
            onChange={(e) => setColumnsValue(e.target.value)}
            variant="outlined"
          />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className={"TableContainer"}>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
              
              <TableBody>{generateTable()}</TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the work was already done.
If you want to maintain your table's data in a multidimensional array (2d in this case), then the name attribute can help you here as it represents row and column number separated by a hyphen.
Just get the name attribute value, split on hyphen and viola! You'll have row and column number, afterwards you just need to use these to set data in the array.

I have updated the [codesandbox (check console to see the data array)](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-heyrovsky-lb9uu?file=/src/demo.js). Updated code is between line 74 & 84

Comment: Thank you so much , I was so confused, couldn't see the obvious part..

Comment: how can i get list of dictionary values where keys are the first row(header)

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify a bit more? I am not sure what do you want to know exactly? Do you mean to access all cell values based on the column header? Maybe an example of the values you are expecting to get will help.

Comment: I am expecting variable(tableArrayData) to have data in this format  [{name: kartikeya, age:11},{name: "Lakshya", age:22},{name:"something",age:34}], In current code, we have 2d array, where first row i will be considering as key (name, age) and other rows will be values (kartikeya,11)  (Lakshya,22) ...

Comment: Ah! thanks for clarifying. It makes more sense now. I have updated the [codesandbox (check console)](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-heyrovsky-lb9uu?file=/src/demo.js) 
I have written an additional function which converts a 2d array to a dictionary but you can easily optimise the code to make it work within the same function, without adding any extra overhead.

Comment: @Lakshya I saw this example of dynamic table which is similar to the problem I am trying to solve. Is there a way I can dynamically add "column header" and "row header" to the same ?

Comment: @Tee Yes, most certainly. There's a method called `generateTable` in the code, there you can add the condition and code for headers. Modified the code to include column headers, you can easily style it and add row header using the similar approach. [codesandbox, use at least 1 row and 1 column to see the result](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-table-forked-lccz8?file=/src/demo.js)

Comment: Thanks, your example was very helpful @Lakshya. I got it working!